# How to use gradle mlExportToFile and REST Transform to Create NDJSON File

Tags: marklogic, ml-gradle, marklogic-10

I am currently using gradle mlExportToFile to export json documents to a file. However, I need the final file to be in newline delimited JSON format, with each document on its own line within the file. I saw that the mlExportToFile + REST transform method could be used to create CSVs, so I am assuming this approach will also work for NDJSON. I've tried just about everything I can think of and the file is still not putting records on their own lines. Any advice is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I don't know what "mlExportToFile" is, but you could probably write a small Gradle task that pretty-prints the json file after it has been exported. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

I think the limitation here is that when the underlying ExportToWriterListener (from the ML Java Client / DMSDK library) will write the document to the File in the format that it's retrieved from ML, which will include newlines by default in it. The ml-gradle task is just a single line of code - `runQueryBatcherJob(new ExportToFileJob())` - so you could easily customize your own task.

I believe you can reuse ExportToFileJob (which is in the marklogic-data-movement-components project) - it has a `getExportListener()` method on it that returns the `ExportToWriterListener` (in the marklogic-client-api project). And that has an `onGenerateOutput(OutputListener)` method, where you can write an `OutputListener` that smushes the JSON into a single line.

That could certainly become a new feature in ml-gradle too; i.e. a property such as `-PnewlineDelimitedJson=true`.

Feel free to [raise a ticket in the ml-gradle project](https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/issues/new/choose) for this (though the enhancement will actually be made in the [marklogic-data-movement-components](https://github.com/marklogic-community/marklogic-data-movement-components) project).

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful!